# Keyboard doesn't load in windows xp after Alureon infection

Tags: windows, keyboard

AVAST detected alureon in a number of system files including atapi.sys and kbdclass.sys
iple 
I quarantined those files, and restarted my machine. After restarting, my keyboard and cdrom did not work (I assumed those drivers would be automatically replaced, but was apparently wrong.)

I went into device manager, and checked for hardware changes, it fixed the cdrom (which works now) and looked as though it fixed the keyboard as well. It did not. After multiple reboots the keyboard is still not recognized. It works up until the XP login screen loads, after which it is completely unresponsive. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Copy the System files you need from a clean PC with XP, you can find what files they are in Avast Quarantine, and the locations of where they belong.

If you do not have access to another XP PC, let me know what they are and I can upload them somewhere for you.

.

Comment: Hey :) The files are atapi.sys and kbdclass.sys ...I don't have access to a clean xp cd :/

Comment: Here you go...http://www.mediafire.com/?r6vp7t7n8qsdvcm

Comment: Copy them to C:\Windows\System32\drivers, then reboot.